# Embedding the console within Qt GUI applicaton

Tags: c++, user-interface, terminal, console

I'm using Qt Creator to build a GUI application, could anyone tell me if it is at all possible to somehow embed the console that pops up within the main dialog window, rather than popping up in a terminal behind it?

I'm building within a Mac OSX enviroment. Cheers!

Comment: Certainly it is possible, but likely a lot of work.  Consider the large effort and weak results from the terminal application within Eclipse.